# Issues while Exporting WAR - Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've developed which works fine in my local machine. When i try to export the WAR for the same, getting the below exception:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ExtraServiceRest: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.extra.restservice:ExtraServiceRest:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.8 -> javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.9 -> javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1: Could not transfer artifact javax.jws:jsr181-api:pom:1.0-MR1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]

Comment: Pom.xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Please make such information available in your post in the future.